# Persistent ignorant Domain Layer

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design

My programming language is C#. I've got a question regarding persistence ignorance within my domain model.

Let's assume I have got a person class like so:

```
public class Person
{
    private string email;

    public string Email
    {
        get { return email; }
        set { email = value; }
    }

    public Person(string email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Now, within my domain model, there is a rule that there cannot be two persons having the same email address. So when instantiating a new person, this needs to be validated as well as when changing email property. So I was wondering how you would solve such a validation within you persistence ignorant domain layer. What I currently do is using a factory pattern for person instantiation in which I inject a person repository. There I can search for other person with the same email address. Like so:

```
public class PersonFactory
{
    private static readonly IPersonRepository personRepository;

    public Person CreateNewPerson(string email)
    {
        Person personWithSameMail = personRepository.GetPersonByEmail(email);

        if (personWithSameMail != null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Email already exists.");

        return new Person(email);
    }

    public PersonFactory(IPersonRepository personRepository)
    {
        this.personRepository = personRepository;
    }
}
```

But using this solution, the check when changing the persons email address (which can be a valid business case) is still not covered. Furthermore the Person class still exposes a public constructor and by bypassing the factory, persons with duplicate email addresses would still be possible.

Any elegeant solutions to this?

P.S. To all data centric people: No, I don't want to validate dupe emails in the data access layer ;)

UPDATE:

Probably this whole question is obsolete anyways. Checking for duplicate emails in terms of a domain model context would always require "something" that is aware of all persons - a root. The "something" could be an address book, or the whole world containing all persons with email addresses. So maybe I am mixing up the programmers need of technically elegant solutions to problems, that exists only because of lack of a complete and well thought out domain model. Can this be the case here? That there is not just a person with an email address floating around in space (hey, space would be my aggregate root here ;) ) just for the fun of existence? But if this would be a real business case like an address book application, address book would be the aggregate root of person and thus could check for all persons in its internal collection to ensure that there is no duplicate email address.

Comment: Why don't you make the constructor internal and also check the email address on updating? And I don't think it's a nice solution to give a repository to a factory. The service function who calls the factory should check if the email address already exists.

Comment: @WouterdeKort: I disagree with your comment: (1) Making the ctor internal doesn't help anything. It still allows the creation of users with duplicate mail addresses. (2) Making the method that calls the factory do the check effectively removes that business rule. It is now up to the caller to enforce this rule. That's just very poor API design

Comment: @DanielHilgarth He mentions explicitly that the public constructor is a problem. A Factory should construct a object with all the dependencies and required values. Mixing business logic with a factory is something I would call bad design.

Comment: @WouterdeKort: I don't agree. A factory is the perfect place to encapsulate business rules that need to be met by all objects of a certain type

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a DDD expert but my take on it is like this.

First of all, for me the biggest flaw in your design is allowing setters on the entity. That means that you **can alter** the state of your entity without the aggregate root knows about it. I would refactor it removing the setters and and letting just setting it through the constructor at the object creation.

Another point. Person entity should not do the validation of the email (in the form of checking if the email is already used or not), because it can only be aware of it's own state and related child entities if she is the root of the aggregate. Then you should have a reference to the repository from the entity which is for me the bad design. That's why you have used the factory I think.

I think the validation should first occur in the UI to fail as fast as possible. But it's not sufficient. When persisting your domain state you should enforce the rule that the Person has an unique email. I think that the validation should occur in the domain service for example called ***PersonRegistrationService*** that would have a reference to the **IPersonRepository** and before adding the person entity to its collection to persist, it would check first if the persons emails is unique. If not I would inform the user with an error and not add the entity.

What do you think ?

Comment: As I understand from what you suggest, the creation of a person should be domain internal. And then, there'll be a registration service which sort of acts like a thing that validates the allowance of a person to even exist with the domain, correct? So this service would get all required initial person properties as arguments and then, by injecting repositories, can take care of "is the person with the given data allowed to exist"?

Comment: I think that the service is in the first place a sort of domain concept. I suggested Registration Service because creating the Person from the thin air doesn't make sense to me. So the responsibility of that service will be to take arguments (or even newed Person entity that at this point of time doesn't belong to the state of the domain), verify with the repository if email is unique and then add the person to it's internal collection (that will be persisted by ORM or other, but it's not just important here).

Comment: Maybe others have another take on this but it seems reasonable to pass by the domain service. In fact it's quite similar to your factory but the difference is that the service has a domain meaning and adds the person after successful validation to the repository (which is a collection of Person entities that is persisted)

Comment: I agree with @ThomasJaskula A Service should be responsible for checking business rules when creating and updating the person. The Factory is not coupled to your repository and is only creating the object.

Comment: I agree. You can never really contain all logic in domain classes anyway, and I think the service layer is a perfect place to validate this type of constraint.